# d3.js - generate color table from array

Tags: d3.js

I would like to generate the d3 color table with multiple rows, in below code, it looks like the color table not updated at all.

```js
color_table()
function color_table() {
 var categorical = [
  { "name" : "schemeAccent", "n": 8},
  { "name" : "schemeDark2", "n": 8},
  { "name" : "schemePastel2", "n": 8},
  { "name" : "schemeSet2", "n": 8},
  { "name" : "schemeSet1", "n": 9},
  { "name" : "schemePastel1", "n": 9},
  { "name" : "schemeCategory10", "n" : 10},
  { "name" : "schemeSet3", "n" : 12 },
  { "name" : "schemePaired", "n": 12},
  //{ "name" : "schemeCategory20", "n" : 20 },
  //{ "name" : "schemeCategory20b", "n" : 20},
  //{ "name" : "schemeCategory20c", "n" : 20 }
]

var width = 400,
    height = 500;

var colorScale = null

var n = 0,
    unit = 0

var svg = d3.select('body').selectAll('cols')
  .data(categorical)
  .enter()
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width',width)
  .attr('height',height/categorical.length)
  .style('border','1px solid red')
  
var bars = svg.selectAll(".bars")
    .data((d,i) => {
      n = d.n
      unit = width/n
      //console.log(n)
      colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3[d.name]); 
      return d3.range(n)})
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bars")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * unit; })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("width", unit)
    .style("fill", (d,i) => colorScale(d) )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your color scales are all the same as you reference the same variable for each: `colorScale`. By evaluating `colorScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3[d.name]);`  for each datum and only afterwards adding the rectangles, they are colored based on the last processed datum to define `colorScale`. This is also why each series has the same rectangle width.

To fix this, we can use d3.local, which appears to be designed for this exact situation:

> D3 locals allow you to define local state independent of data. For
> instance, when rendering small multiples of time-series data, you
> might want the same x-scale for all charts but distinct y-scales to
> compare the relative performance of each metric. ([docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#local-variables))

With d3 local we can hold the distinct color scales and width values for each series:

```
var localScale = d3.local();
var localWidth = d3.local();
```

And we can set their values for each parent node as follows using `local.set`, which sets a value for a specified node (2nd and 1st parameters respectively):

```
var svg = d3.select('body').selectAll('cols')
  .data(categorical)
  .enter()
  .append('svg')
  .each(function(d) {
    localScale.set(this,d3.scaleOrdinal(d3[d.name]));
    localWidth.set(this,width/d.n);
  })
```

To get the value we can use `local.get(node)`, for the child nodes. While we haven't defined a local value for the child nodes, `local.get` will find the nearest ancestor with a defined value, so we can supply the rectangle to `local.get`:

```
var bars = svg.selectAll(".bars")
   .data(d => d3.range(d.n))
   .enter().append("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) { 
        return i * localWidth.get(this); 
   })
   .attr("width", function() {
     return localWidth.get(this)
   })
   .style("fill", function(d) {
      return localScale.get(this)(d) ;
  })
  ...
```

*I've changed the data being passed to simply `d3.range(d.n)` as we no longer need to calculate anything else here.*

Altogether this gives us:

```js
color_table()
function color_table() {
 var categorical = [
  { "name" : "schemeAccent", "n": 8},
  { "name" : "schemeDark2", "n": 8},
  { "name" : "schemePastel2", "n": 8},
  { "name" : "schemeSet2", "n": 8},
  { "name" : "schemeSet1", "n": 9},
  { "name" : "schemePastel1", "n": 9},
  { "name" : "schemeCategory10", "n" : 10},
  { "name" : "schemeSet3", "n" : 12 },
  { "name" : "schemePaired", "n": 12},
]

var width = 400,
    height = 500;

var localScale = d3.local();
var localWidth = d3.local();

var n = 0,
    unit = 0

var svg = d3.select('body').selectAll('cols')
  .data(categorical)
  .enter()
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width',width)
  .attr('height',height/categorical.length)
  .style('border','1px solid red')
  .each(function(d) {
    localScale.set(this,d3.scaleOrdinal(d3[d.name]));
    localWidth.set(this,width/d.n);
  })
  
var bars = svg.selectAll(".bars")
    .data(d => d3.range(d.n))
  .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bars")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return i * localWidth.get(this); })
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("width", function() {
      return localWidth.get(this)
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return localScale.get(this)(d) ;
    })
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Providing:

[image]

An alternative approach would be to store the scale on the datum itself, either the parent or the child, but d3.local is designed for this purpose and is likely the simplest solution.

Comment: Great answer, that's what I want, BTW, how do you get the png file from the svg? I know screencap can do it but it's not good.

Comment: This was a screen grab - there are a handful of questions on exporting to png from svg on SO (with or without d3) - though I'm not familiar enough with any or the methods used to be in a position to make a recommendation on how to do so or which question/reference is valid/best/useful.